# Can I create a bag of objects that will hold different kinds o generic objects?

Tags: c#, generics

This one was hard to come up with a good title, so I gave my best shot at it.

Here is the problem:

```
Dictionary<string,ILayer> _layers = new Dictionary<string,ILayer>();
_layers.Add("IntLayer",new Layer<int>());
_layers.Add("GuidLayer",new Layer<Guid>());
Guid value = _layers["GuidLayer"].GetValue(int x, int y);
```

The classes:

```
public class Layer<T> : ILayer
{
    public T[,] Matrix { get; set; }

    public T GetValue(int x, int y)
    {
        return Matrix[x, y];
    }
}   

public interface ILayer
{
    //T GetValue(int x, int y);
}
```

The idea is to be able to store different kinds of layers, and avoid the explicit casting. Although one would know the type when trying to get a value so it could be casted safely, but if I ever want to apply something across the layer it would make things a little more complicated there for a "generic" method would be better.

Is it possible to create this scenario? Should I be going a completely different way about this problem?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean with *"want to apply something across the layer it would make things a little more complicated there for a "generic" method would be better."*? If you can put *"something"* across all layers (i.e., the concrete *Layer<T>* types don't matter), then surely you can declare an appropriate method in the interface. If the nature of that *"something"* would depend on the concrete *Layer<T>* type, then you would not be able to apply that *"something"* accross all layers anyhow...

Comment: What I want is a way to get/set values, without having to specifically care about the type (i.e.: _layers["x"].GetValue(1,1) == _layers["y"].GetValue(1,1), or foreach(layer) aLayer.GetValue(1,1) == 34).
That situation would be ideal, so in the end the dictionary would appear to have the same behavior as a simple dictionary.

Comment: If you look a the example I have up there, you will see that I have the method commented because it won't compile, if I try like that. Now Volma's suggestion works better, and might be the only solution.

Comment: Yepp, forget my last comment (which i deleted, btw). Didn't read your question/code properly. It looks to me that the option 2 in Volma's answer (extension method) is the way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid explicit casting in the client code, there are couple of options I can think about:

**Option 1**

```
public interface ILayer
{
    U GetValue<U>(int x, int y);
}

public class Layer<T> : ILayer
{
    public T[,] Matrix { get; set; }

    U ILayer.GetValue<U>(int x, int y)
    {
        return (U) (object) Matrix[x, y];
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
public interface ILayer
    {
    }

    public class Layer<T> : ILayer
    {
        public T[,] Matrix { get; set; }

        public T GetValue(int x, int y)
        {
            return Matrix[x, y];
        }
    }

    public static class LayerExtensions
    {
        public static U GetValue<U>(this ILayer layer, int x, int y)
        {
            return ((Layer<U>)layer).GetValue(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting and might be the only way out, but the ideal condition would be (Ex.: T GetValue(int x, int y). 
That way I don't have to care about the type of T, but the syntax does not allow because it does not know T on the interface.